# How to detect a specific URL with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I try to write a regex in order to check if there is a floor, elevator and the number of level in an URL (knowing that the name and the number of level can change).

The URLs look like that:

> https://www.mywebsite.com/root/floor-a-1-45/
>   https://www.mywebsite.com/root/floor-b-2-15/

I also began to write this code, but I don't see how to resolve my problem.

```
import re
def is_http_url(s):
    if re.match('https?://(?:www)?(?:[\w-]{2,255}(?:\.\w{2,6}){1,2})(?:/[\w&%?#-]{1,300})?',s):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print is_http_url("https://www.mywebsite.com/root/floor-a-1-50/")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Declare regex patterns with `r''`. Also, maybe this one is what you need: [`https?://(?:www)?(?:[\w-]{2,255}(?:\.\w+){1,2})(?:/[\w&%?#-]{1,300})*/?`](https://regex101.com/r/vW2bC9/1)?

Comment: Are you searching for URLs in an arbitrary text or do you already have the URL and want to verify it? If so, you could simplify the task and just check the last path segment, would simplify the regex quite a lot (or perhaps split a task into two parts - recognition of URLs and validation of the URLs found).

Comment: I searching the Urls in an arbitrary text, and I try to check the last path segment.

Comment: Thanks, I check this option

Answer (score 0):

```
https?://(?:www)?(?:[\w.-]{2,255}(?:\.\w{2,6}){1,2})(?:/[\w&%?#-]{0,300})*
```

You need to tweak your regex to accept more than 1 `/aasd` groups.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/31

Also put your regex in `r` so as to avoid escaping issues

```
re.match(r'https?://(?:www)?(?:[\w.-]{2,255}(?:\.\w{2,6}){1,2})(?:/[\w&%?#-]{0,300})*',s)
```